# Time Data does not match format "'%H:%M.%S%f'"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to forecast time series data.
The time series data in my csv file is in the form 0:00.000
Hence, I indexed the time series data column as follows:

```
df.columns=['Elapsed','I']
df['Elapsed']=pd.to_datetime(df['Elapsed'], format='%H:%M.%S%f')
df['Elapsed']=df['Elapsed'].dt.time
df.set_index('Elapsed', inplace=True)
```

Then later I split my data into the test section and the train section

```
train = df.loc['0:00.000':'0:28.778']
test = df.loc['0:28.779':]
```

My stack trace is
[image]
[image]
An extract of my data is:

[image]

Can anyone explain how to prevent this error from occuring?

Comment: can you please paste the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: And can you show some example data?

Comment: Isn't this self-explanatory: `'0:00.000' does not match format "'%H:%M.%S%f'"` is indeed true. See http://strftime.org/ for tips.

Comment: by "the exact error", I mean the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question has now changed, I'll write a new answer.

Your dataframe is indexed by instances of `datetime.time`, but you're trying to slice it with strings - pandas doesn't want to compare strings with times.

To get your slicing to work, try this:

```
split_from = datetime.datetime.strptime('0:00.000', '%H:%M.%S%f').time()
split_to = datetime.datetime.strptime('0:28.778', '%H:%M.%S%f').time()
train = df[split_from:split_to]
```

It would also be useful to hold the format in a variable since you're now using it in several places.

Or if you have fixed split times, you could instead do

```
split_from = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
split_to = datetime.time(0, 28, 77.8)
train = df[split_from:split_to]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, I'm just guessing, but here goes:

I'm guessing your original data in the 'Elapsed' column looks like

```
'12:34.5678'
'12:35.1234'
```

In particular, it has quotes each side of the numbers. Otherwise your line

```
df['Elapsed']=pd.to_datetime(df['Elapsed'], format="'%H:%M.%S%f'")
```

would fail.

So the error message is telling you that your slicing times have the wrong format: they are missing quotes on each side. Change it to

```
train = df.loc["'0:00.000'":"'0:28.778'"]
```

(likewise for the next line) and hopefully that will sort it out.

If you can extract your source data in a way that avoids having quote characters in the timestamps, you'll probably find things a little simpler.

Comment: I actually do not have quote characters around my timestamps

Comment: In that case please answer the first question I left as a comment: "can you please paste the exact error you are seeing?"